# Installing Fedora 20 on Windows 10

Tags: linux, fedora20

Good day. I just purchased and set up my HP desktop which is running windows 10.

I was given a Fedora 20 disk from work and I wish to install it, I am cautious at the moment. Thus what should I expect when I insert the CD w/ Fedora 20 on it.

Any tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have no idea where this question is on topic, but it isn't here.

Comment: You should check out the [Unix&Linux Stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) for relavant posts and post this question there as it's off topic for stackoverflow. In general unless you are looking to wipe out wndows on your system, you will need to google dual boot options for Windows 10 or virtual machine options or live cd's.

Answer (score 0):

No risk at all (given it is a genuine copy). I would recommend using VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) which would allow you to install Fedora on a VM on your laptop without risk of destroying your Windows installation.